# Creating a std::shared_ptr object and returning it to the R side (Rcpp)

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm trying to write a R bindings for a C++ script using Rcpp. One of the functions expects a `std::shared_ptr object`. I find it difficult to initialize the `std::shared_ptr` obj and return it to the R side as a `Rcpp::XPtr` object.

I've tried (minimal example):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <Rcpp.h> 
using namespace Rcpp;
using std::cout;


class TestClass {
  public:
    int value;

    TestClass(int initial_val) {
      value = initial_val;
    };

};


//[[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP get_test_obj() {
  Rcpp::XPtr<std::shared_ptr<TestClass>> ptr(std::make_shared<TestClass>(5), true);
  return ptr;
};
```

But get the following error:

```
 no matching function for call to 'Rcpp::XPtr<std::shared_ptr<TestClass> >::XPtr(std::shared_ptr<TestClass>, bool)'
```

Any ideas on how to do this? Or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: There are a few projects using `Rcpp::XPtr`, maybe looking more closely at what they do can help you here?

Comment: And there are [a number of other questions here showing `Rcpp::XPtr`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brcpp%5D+XPtr).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt that the R side would expect to have a std::shared_ptr passed to it. I'm assuming that some other code in your source relies on std::shared_ptr, but you want to pass the inner raw pointer to R. I'm also assuming that the std::shared_ptr's lifetime is more appropriately managed in your code, since the code as presented would make the std::shared_ptr fall out of scope after the function and crash on the next dereference.

In any case, if you wanted to just pass the inner raw pointer to R, you'd do it like this (contrived):

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP get_test_obj() {
  std::shared_ptr<TestClass> s_ptr = std::make_shared<TestClass>(5);
  Rcpp::XPtr<TestClass> x_ptr(s_ptr.get(), true);
  return x_ptr;
};
```

Comment: Compiler says that ‘shared_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’. Is it still working?

Comment: Enable support for the C++11.

Answer (score 9):

The answer from @d3coy has pretty much all the information. `Rcpp::XPtr` is a template smart pointer class, it's parameter is the pointee class, not the class it points to. So a `Rcpp::XPtr<std::shared_ptr<TestClass>>` would be a smart pointer to a `std::shared_ptr<TestClass>*`. Note the `*`, that's the important bit.

When a `shared_ptr` goes out of scope, if that's the last holder of the raw pointer, the raw pointer might get deleted. That's definitely not what you want.

Instead you can create a raw pointer with `new` and feed `XPtr` with that. This pointer will get `delete`d when the garbage colector collects the R object undelying the `XPtr`, which is what you usually want when you deal with external pointers.

I know the current guidelines is to use `make_unique` and `make_shared` as much as possible instead of `new` but in this case you need `new`. The smartness comes from `XPtr`, if you mix it with `shared_ptr` they will get in the way of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the tips and 'pointers'. Not sure if this is the correct way to respond, but I thought I'd enter the solution that I found.

The point is that the R side indeed doesn't necessarily require the `std::shared_ptr`. However I'm interfacing with an existing C++ library. I need to instantiate a `std::shared_ptr<TestClass>` of the library (using R) and feed in back into the C++ algorithm which expects a `std::shared_ptr<TestClass>`.

The way I solved it is as follows (example and untested):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <Rcpp.h> 
using namespace Rcpp;
using std::cout;


class TestClass {
  public:
  int value;
  TestClass(int initial_val): value(initial_val) {}

};

class TestClassContainer {
  public
  std::shared_ptr<TestClass> test_class_obj;
  TestClassContainer(): test_class_obj(std::make_shared<TestClass>()) {} 
};

//[[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP get_test_obj() {
  Rcpp::XPtr<TestClassContainer> ptr(new TestClassContainer(), true);
  return ptr;
};

//[[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP do_something_with_shared_ptr_testclass(SEXP test_container_obj) {
  Rcpp::XPtr<ResourceContainer> test_ptr(test_container_obj);
  ExternalLib::do_function(test_container_obj->test_class_obj);
};
```

Then in R I can do:

```
test_container <- get_test_obj()
do_something_with_shared_ptr_testclass(test_container)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement on this topic (it took me a couple of days of my life since I'm a C++ newbie), the code below was based on Bart's solution above, tested, and confirmed. If someday someone come with a simpler solution, please let me know!

PS: Dirk's resources are marvelous (grateful for all your work), but I didn't manage to find any Rcpp-based packages dealing with this issue =/

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <memory>
using namespace Rcpp;

// A simple class for testing ----------------------------
class A{
public:
  int value;
  A(int x);
};
A::A(int x) {this->value = x + 10;}

using APtr = std::shared_ptr<A>;

class AWrapper{
public:
  APtr a_wrap;
  AWrapper(int x): a_wrap(new A(x)){};
};

// The regular way to access an instance of a class using XPtr ----------------------------
// Everything is fine here, nothing to do.
// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<A> A_constructor(int x) {
  A *a = new A(x);
  XPtr<A> out(a, true);
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int A_test(XPtr<A> x) {
  return x->value;
}

// THE PROBLEM ----------------------------
// A given C++ lib expect to receive an shared_ptr instead of a class instance itself.
// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<APtr> APtr_constructor(int x) {
  APtr a = std::make_shared<A>(x);
  std::cout << a->value << std::endl;
  XPtr<APtr> out_ptr(&a, true); // <--------------- how do I wrap 'a' here??
  return out_ptr;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int APtr_test(XPtr<APtr> x) {
  return x->get()->value; // <--------------- how do I access the A instance pointed by APtr x (which was wrapped by XPtr)?
}

// Wrapper solution ----------------------------
// Using an auxiliary class to store a APtr and the XPtr an instance of it.
// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<AWrapper> AWrapper_constructor(int x) {
  AWrapper *a_w = new AWrapper(x);
  XPtr<AWrapper> out_ptr(a_w, true);
  return out_ptr;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int AWrapper_test(XPtr<AWrapper> x) {
  return x->a_wrap->value;
}

/*** R
# Working correctly ------------------------------------
a <- A_constructor(42)
A_test(a)
# > [1] 52
# NOT working ------------------------------------------
a_ptr <- APtr_constructor(42)
APtr_test(a_ptr)
# > [1] -1652502752 # garbage, might vary
# working ------------------------------------------
a_w <- AWrapper_constructor(42)
AWrapper_test(a_w)
# > [1] 52
*/
```