# Rcpp boost::dynamic_bitset implementation

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

I'm trying to implement a bit vector in R (I'm currently using the R bit package but would like to move away from that).
I thought to use the boost *dynamic_bitset* class. 
The idea is to write a cpp function that will accept a logical vector from R and store the values in a *dynamic_bitset*.

My problem is that most of the Rcpp examples I found return an R data structure, but I specifically want to avoid that from happening, while still allowing access from R through accessors I'll overload (e.g: as.logical, [] etc.). What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217102/creating-a-stdshared-ptr-object-and-returning-it-to-the-r-side-rcpp

Answer (score 0):

You write

> most of the Rcpp examples I found return an R data structure

and that is the essence of it.  Rcpp communicates with R via the `.Call()` interface and can only *receive* and *return* such R data structures: `SEXP`.  Rcpp converts to and from for you, but it cannot change the fact the interface is given to use and *fixed*.  You can only return R data structures to R.  Everything needs to be mapped (or copied) to them.