# How to pass a class object from an Rcpp module back into C++?

Tags: r, c++14, rcpp

I have a C++ codebase that I'm exposing to R using Rcpp modules. Specifically, I use an interface pattern where the class(es) I expose is actually an abstraction layer on top of the underlying object, which is the implementation.

The class(es) I'm dealing with also interact with each other, and have methods that take as arguments shared pointers to objects. I'm having trouble figuring out the right way to expose these methods to R.

Eg here is some code. The `TestClass::combine` method takes a pointer to another `TestClass` object and does stuff with it. When I try to compile this code, I get compiler errors (see below) when I add the corresponding interface method `ITestClass::combine` to the module.

Implementation:

```cpp
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass(int const& n, double const& x)
        : n(n), x(x)
    {}

    const double get_x() {
        return x;
    }

    double combine(std::shared_ptr<TestClass> obj) {
        return x + obj->get_x();
    }

protected:
    int n;
    double x;
};
```

Interface:

```cpp
//' @export ITestClass
class ITestClass
{
public:
    ITestClass(int const& in_n, double const& in_x)
        : impl(in_n, in_x)
    {}

    double get_x() {
        return impl.get_x();
    }

    double combine(ITestClass obj) {
        return impl.combine(obj.get_object_ptr());
    }

    std::shared_ptr<TestClass> get_object_ptr() {
        std::shared_ptr<TestClass> ptr(&impl);
        return ptr;
    }

private:
    TestClass impl;
};

RCPP_MODULE(RTestClassModule)
{
    class_<ITestClass>("ITestClass")
        .constructor<int, double>()
        .method("get_x", &ITestClass::get_x, "get_x")
        .method("combine", &ITestClass::combine, "combine"); // this line errors out
}
```

A sample of the errors I get:

```
    In file included from C:/Rlib/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/as.h:25,
                    from C:/Rlib/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:168,
                    from C:/Rlib/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                    from interface1.cpp:2:
   C:/Rlib/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/Exporter.h: In instantiation of 'Rcpp::traits::Exporter<T>::Exporter(SEXP) [with T = testpkg::ITestClass; SEXP = SEXPREC*]':
   C:/Rlib/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/as.h:87:41:   required from 'T Rcpp::internal::as(SEXP, Rcpp::traits::r_type_generic_tag) [with T = testpkg::ITestClass; SEXP = SEXPREC*]'
   C:/Rlib/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/as.h:152:31:   required from 'T Rcpp::as(SEXP) [with T = testpkg::ITestClass; SEXP = SEXPREC*]'
   C:/Rlib/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/InputParameter.h:34:43:   required from 'Rcpp::InputParameter<T>::operator T() [with T = testpkg::ITestClass]'
   C:/Rlib/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/module/Module_generated_CppMethod.h:111:69:   required from 'SEXPREC* Rcpp::CppMethod1<Class, RESULT_TYPE, U0>::operator()(Class*, SEXPREC**) [with Class = testpkg::ITestClass; RESULT_TYPE = double; U0 = testpkg::ITestClass; SEXP = SEXPREC*]'
   C:/Rlib/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/module/Module_generated_CppMethod.h:109:10:   required from here
   C:/Rlib/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/Exporter.h:31:31: error: no matching function for 
call to 'testpkg::ITestClass::ITestClass(SEXPREC*&)'
          Exporter( SEXP x ) : t(x){}
                                  ^
   interface1.cpp:17:5: note: candidate: 'testpkg::ITestClass::ITestClass(SEXP, const int&, const double&)'
        ITestClass(SEXP in_date, int const& in_n, double const& in_x)
        ^~~~~~~~~~
   interface1.cpp:17:5: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
   interface1.cpp:14:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr testpkg::ITestClass::ITestClass(const testpkg::ITestClass&)'
    class ITestClass
          ^~~~~~~~~~
   interface1.cpp:14:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'SEXP' {aka 'SEXPREC*'} to 'const testpkg::ITestClass&'
   interface1.cpp:14:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr testpkg::ITestClass::ITestClass(testpkg::ITestClass&&)'
   interface1.cpp:14:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'SEXP' {aka 'SEXPREC*'} to 'testpkg::ITestClass&&'
```

How do I define `ITestClass::combine` so that it can be called from R?

Comment: Also, if at all possible, I don't want to expose `TestClass` to R. That's what the interface layer is for, R should not know nor care about the implementation.

Comment: Where tje object comes from (here: an Rcpp Modules snippet) does not matter, What matters is that R only lets us use `.Call(SEXP a, SEXP b, ....)` so whatever we have we need to map to R's `SEXP`.  Which has entire other vignette (R Extending) dedicated to it.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I'm well aware that Rcpp has to work within the constraints of the 1990s-era R API. In fact I was explaining this to the guys when they complained about it. But I still need a solution that's better than the one I've got (which is actually faulty since the shared pointer destroys the object in `obj2` after 1 use).

Comment: The member function `double combine(ITestClass obj)` simply does not fit the `SEXP .Call(SEXP a, SEXP b, ...)` mold _until you provide a wrapper for `ITestClass`_ via C++ code.  The compiler cannot pass this through for you, hence the error.

Comment: Right, I figured that out which is why in my answer I change it to `combine(SEXP)`. But it would be nice if I could pass the object `obj2` directly, rather than `obj2$get_object()`. Maybe there's a way to pull apart the structure of `obj2` in C++?

Comment: Yes, that's the thing: All 'higher-level' `struct` or `class` objects would have to be decomposed into atomistics `double`, `int`, `char`, ... that R knows.  Or else ... you let them be and just pass `XPtr` to them around.

Comment: I did notice that the refclass created by the module has a `.cppclass` property which appears to be a pointer to the underlying object. It would be great if someone could post an answer showing how to access this from a SEXP 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution, one that has the preferred interface for `combine` and doesn't seem to run into problems with garbage collection.

A couple of points:

- Because the underlying API works extensively with shared pointers, rather than storing a `TestClass` object in `impl`, I store a `std::shared_ptr<TestClass>`. This is referenced directly, rather than creating new shared ptrs from scratch (which crash R when they get destroyed).
- I leverage the internal structure of the returned refclass object from an Rcpp module. In particular, it has a `.pointer` member that is a pointer to the underlying C++ object. So I can dereference that to get the `impl` member.

New interface:

```cpp
//' @export ITestClass2
class ITestClass2
{
public:
    ITestClass2(int const& in_n, double const& in_x)
        : impl(in_n, in_x))
    {}

    double get_x()
    {
        return impl->get_x();
    }

    double combine(Environment obj)
    {
        SEXP objptr = obj[".pointer"];
        ITestClass2* ptr = (ITestClass2*) R_ExternalPtrAddr(objptr);
        return impl->combine(ptr->get_object_ptr());
    }

// this doesn't need to be seen from R
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<TestClass> get_object_ptr()
    {
        return impl;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<TestClass> impl;
};

RCPP_MODULE(RTestClassModule2)
{
    class_<ITestClass2>("ITestClass2")
        .constructor<int, double>()
        .method("get_x", &ITestClass2::get_x, "get_x")
        .method("combine", &ITestClass2::combine, "combine")
    ;
}
```

Call this in R as follows:

```r
obj <- new(ITestClass2, 1, pi)
obj2 <- new(ITestClass2, 2, exp(1))
obj$combine(obj2)
```

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel any comments?

Comment: Sorry I don't run a code-commenting service.  We do have a mailing list, maybe use that?

Comment: But if it works, it works. Maybe write it up for the Rcpp Gallery?

Comment: Awesome, thank you for that, I was trying `XPtr` and although it worked it was crashing my application if I ran the function multiple times, IDK why though.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: see better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70151613/474349)

I found a rather kludgy solution that involves calling the R foreign language API directly:

```cpp
class ITestClass {

    ...

    double combine(SEXP obj) {
        TestClass* ptr = (TestClass*) R_ExternalPtrAddr(obj);
        std::shared_ptr<TestClass> sptr(ptr);
        return impl.combine(sptr);
    }

    Rcpp::XPtr<TestClass> get_object() {
        return Rcpp::XPtr<TestClass>(&impl);
    }
}
```

```r
obj1 <- new(ITestClass, 1, pi)
obj2 <- new(ITestClass, 2, -0.1)

obj1$combine(obj2$get_object())
# [1] 3.041593
```

This isn't great for a couple of reasons:

- On the R side, I have to pass `obj$get_object()` as the argument to `combine`, which is highly non-intuitive
- I've seen [answers noting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26220868/474349) that `Rcpp::XPtr` and `std::shared_ptr` don't work well together, since they both try to manage the memory pointed to

Hopefully there's a better solution out there.

Comment: That answer is from 2014 and needs context. When you look inside any complicated package managing objects (`tiledb`, `arrow`, ...) you see lots of `XPtr` wrapping `shared_ptr` objects.  Remember that at the end of the day ... `XPtr` is all we have to connect to an external object from the API of R.

Comment: See new answer, any comments?

Comment: Sorry I don't run a code-commenting service.  We do have a mailing list, maybe use that?

Comment: But if it works, it works. Maybe write it up for the Rcpp Gallery?